# Trying to reduce Decimal property gives: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, nsdecimalnumber

I have a Core Data Entity called `Transaction` with the property `value` of type `Decimal`.

I'm trying to reduce an array of Transactions, to sum the `value` attribute:

```
private var transactions = [Transaction]() {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = transactions.reduce(0.0) { $0.decimalNumberByAdding($1.value) }
    }
}
```

But this gives compiler error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

How can I reduce an array of objects by summing an Decimal property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that despite the type on my data model was set to `Decimal`, actually the type is `NSDecimalNumber`.

[image]

So it had to be:

```
let total = transactions.reduce(NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 0)) { $0.adding($1.value ?? NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 0)) }
navigationItem.title = "$ \(total)"
```